# Generating sharing message and shortened URL to Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, mobile, url-shortener

I am using a Twitter ghetto sharing on a very simple Python based mobile site

```
 return "http://mobile.twitter.com/home?status=" + urllib.quote(link)
```

I'd like to change the sharing so that Twitter messages gets the page title (I have it) and shortened URL.

Does there exist any general libraries/micro-frameworks for this purposes for Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend implementing a URL-shortener API (ie: bit.ly). Even further, there are API wrappers available for most of these popular services (ie: Python API wrapper for bit.ly - http://code.google.com/p/python-bitly/).